# vimrc wrap variable definition

Tags: vim

I have a very long variable definition and I want to wrap it. How can I wrap the string without breaking it

```
let g:ctrlp_user_command = 'ag %s -l --nocolor --hidden --ignore=".git" --ignore="public" --ignore="node_modules" --ignore="bower_components" -g ""'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap a string to multiple lines by beginning the next line with a backslash (`\`). Whitespace before the backslash is ignored.

```
let g:ctrlp_user_command = 'ag %s -l --nocolor --hidden --ignore=".git"
    \ --ignore="public" --ignore="node_modules"
    \ --ignore="bower_components" -g ""'
```